# jaxws client adds boundary information while sending base64Binary data

Tags: xsd, base64, weblogic, jax-ws, mtom

I have java module(ear) with jaxws client calling external system and passing base64Binary information.
I have wsdl with element:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="content" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
```

When module is deployed to Weblogic(12c) I make soap call and see error:

HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'multipart/related; type="text/xml"; boundary="uuid:b3cc9fac-4eb7-4d34-83c6-81a632d93c8d"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

I took dump and see that my request is passing with additional information as if I have MTOM feature enabled.

```
<content xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">dGhpbmsgYWJvdXQgaXQ=</contents>
```

When I run tests from my local machine I see my soap request with inline content information:

```
<content>dGhpbmsgYWJvdXQgaXQ=</content>
```

if I make changes to xsd: change type base64Binary to string, every thing works fine.

I have logged information to figure out is feature enabled running application on Weblogic:

```
logger.info("MTOM is enabled={}",((SOAPBinding)((BindingProvider) port).getBinding()).isMTOMEnabled());
```

It shows that feature is disabled.

Why do this happen ? How can I fix it ? How can I remove boundary information?

Answer (score 0):

After research I figured out why all this happened

I use SoapHandler to log(and only log) my request/response.

If I remove it - every thing works fine. file content is sent as expected without any attachments and boundary information.

I added few lines to my soapHandler:

```
if ((Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {                
   context.getMessage().removeAllAttachments();
   context.getMessage().getMimeHeaders().removeAllHeaders();
   
   context.getMessage();
}
```

This removed all unwanted information from request and it works as expected with soapHandler.